# Adding only certain inputs within a div

Tags: javascript, html, input

Currently I have a function that adds all input within a div (`inputsite`) and then subtracts that total from another input (`siteinput`). This worked great, but I have added more inputs to the div that will contain text; this will invoke the "not a readable number" alert:

```
function site_change() {{
         var sites= document.getElementById('sitesinput').value;    
         var sum= 0;
         var inputs= document.getElementById('inputsite').getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (var i= inputs.length; i-->0;) {
             var v= inputs[i].value.split(',').join('.').split(' ').join('');
             if (isNaN(+v))
                 alert(inputs[i].value+' is not a readable number');
             else
                 sum+= +v;
         }
         var phones= document.getElementById('phonesinput').value;
         document.getElementById('siteresult').innerHTML = phones-sum;
    };

}
```

An example of input that needs to be included is:

```
<input name="site1" type="text" size="3" value="0" />
```

And this needs to be excluded:

```
<input name="site1PC" type="text" size="7" maxlength="7"/>
```

How do I adjust the function so that it only picks up the ones named `site1`, `site2`, `site3`, etc and not `site1PC`, `site2PC`, `site3PC`, etc?

Thanks,
Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `if (inputs[i].getAttribute('name').match(/^site\d+$/))`

```
function site_change() {
         var sites= document.getElementById('sitesinput').value;    
         var sum= 0;
         var inputs= document.getElementById('inputsite').getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (var i= inputs.length; i-->0;) {
            if (inputs[i].getAttribute('name').match(/^site\d+$/))
            {
             var v= inputs[i].value.split(',').join('.').split(' ').join('');
             if (isNaN(+v))
                 alert(inputs[i].value+' is not a readable number');
             else
                 sum+= +v;
            }
         }
         var phones= document.getElementById('phonesinput').value;
         document.getElementById('siteresult').innerHTML = phones-sum;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

Hope this helps.

```
function site_change() {{
         var sites= document.getElementById('sitesinput').value;    
         var sum= 0;
         var inputs= document.getElementById('inputsite').getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (var i= inputs.length; i-->0;) {
             if(input.hasClass('ignore')){return;} // looking for this(give your input class='ignore' to be excluded.

             var v= inputs[i].value.split(',').join('.').split(' ').join('');
             if (isNaN(+v))
                 alert(inputs[i].value+' is not a readable number');
             else
                 sum+= +v;
         }
         var phones= document.getElementById('phonesinput').value;
         document.getElementById('siteresult').innerHTML = phones-sum;
    };

}
```